# angularjs with jasmine- TypeError: $controller is not a function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Here is my controller:

```
angular.module('someapp', [])
      .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, dataservice, $stateParams) {
           $scope.messageid = parseInt($stateParams.messageid);
});
```

**spec file:**

```
describe('TestCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(module('someapp'));

    var $controller;
    $stateParameters = { messageid: 100 };
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    it('should set value of messageid', function() {
        var controller = $controller('TestCtrl', {
            $stateParams: $stateParameters
        });
        expect($scope.messageid).toEqual($stateParameters.messageid);
    });
});
```

But it's giving error: `TypeError: $controller is not a function`

can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Try removing var $controller;

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('someapp', [])
      .controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope',  '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams) {
           $scope.messageid = parseInt($stateParams.messageid);
}]);

describe('TestCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(module('someapp'));

    var $controller;
    $stateParameters = { messageid: 100 };
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    it('should set value of messageid', function() {
        var controller = $controller('TestCtrl', {
            $stateParams: $stateParameters;
        });
        expect($scope.messageid).toEqual($stateParameters.messageid);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('TestCtrl', function() {
    var $scope, dataservice;
    beforeEach(module('someapp'));
    module(function ($provide) {
      // Mock dataservice
      $provide.service('dataservice', function () {
            // Assuming you have a getData function in dataservice
            this.getData = jasmine.createSpy('getData');
        });
    });
    //var $controller;
    var $stateParameters = { messageid: 100 };
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _dataservice_){
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        dataservice = _dataservice_
        $controller('TestCtrl', {
            $scope : $scope,
            dataservice: dataservice,
            $stateParams: $stateParameters
        });
    }));

    it('should set value of messageid', function() {
        expect($scope.messageid).toEqual($stateParameters.messageid);
    });
});
```